# Appery.io Azure SQL Connection

Tags: azure-sql-database, appery.io

Has anyone been successful making a connection from Appery.io API Express to an Azure SQL Database? If so can you help me please?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error when trying to do so?  If so, post the error details.  Note that by default Azure SQL will only allow incoming connections from within the Azure platform only - you may need to open up connections from another IP Address.

Comment: No error, connection fails. Yes I have opened the required IPs, even tired opening all for a test and still no connection. This is a Appery.io issue I can connect from other outside clients.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am looking at this. What driver are you using to connect from Appery.io API Express?

Answer (score 0):

i actually have an app that connects to azure sql successfully. Make sure for your database, you have added the firewall rules for:

```
 app5.appery.io.  -52.7.79.49
 app6.appery.io.  -52.6.213.128
 aex1.appery.io.  -52.21.190.50
 aex2.appery.io.  -52.6.184.169
 aex3.appery.io.  -52.6.184.169
 aex4.appery.io.  -52.204.187.85
```

Once you have those set in azure, make sure you have your endpoint address from your azure aql settings.
On Appery.io, open Api Express and add new database connection, put in all of the settings with you username and password, you should get a successful test, once thats done then you and create a new project with the new database connection you created before. Let me know if its still not working. I struggled with this issue before and got it to work.